# How to access the information from an excel file which is updating live through xlwings?

Tags: python

I am writing into an excel file using xlwings which is constantly getting updated in 15 seconds.

Now I want to use the information from the excel file and make charts out of it by using matplotlib.
I tried using to read it through pandas but I am not able to do so, might be since the file is opened.

How can matplotlib use the information from this file ?